# Windows Batch Script for 2 Cases

Tags: mysql, sqlite, batch-file

I use the following .bat script

```
set varSearch="C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test-folder\*.crypt8"
for /f %%i in ('dir %varSearch% /B ') do set varSearch= %%i
WhatsAppViewer.exe -decrypt8 %myName% key exp.db

sqlite3.exe exp.db<command.txt
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u admin -p1234 < query.txt
```

The basic function is to find a file thats ending with .crypt8, decrypt it, save as csv and import to mysql. Its working correctly

But i need some extra features

> Case1

The folder contains more than 1 file, and every file has to be processed, but only once

> Case 2

Everyday at least one file gets added. It would be superb if the .bat could be scheduled as a task, and run every night and just process the new added files.

Does anybody has a solution for this?

Comment: Where the `%myName%` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

## Case 2

The forfiles command processes groups of files based on date. This does files made today only.

```
forfiles /d 0 /m *.crypt8 /c "cmd /c echo @fname in @path"
```

## Case 1

Your code has errors, it may work but not under all conditions.

The easist way is to put the sequence of commands in a batchfile for a file (%1) which is passed on command line, and use forfiles to call it.